# Работа с веб-камерой Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-basic, web-camera

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работа с веб-камерой. Не понимаю в чем проблема...

```
 Public Class Form1 
      Public Touchless As New TouchlessLib.TouchlessMgr 
      Public Webka As TouchlessLib.Camera=Touchless.Cameras.Item(0) 

      Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
           Touchless.CurrentCamera = Webka 
           Touchless.CurrentCamera.CaptureHeight = 480 
           Touchless.CurrentCamera.CaptureWidth = 640 
      End Sub 

      Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
            PictureBox1.Image = Touchless.CurrentCamera.GetCurrentImage 
      End Sub 

      Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
            Touchless.CurrentCamera.GetCurrentImage.Save("D:/1.bmp") 
      End Sub 
 End Class
```

Comment: Приложите код в виде текста, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавила уже...